# Add name and email to a state dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I have an event app. Where a user comes add number of people. Then based on the number of people I show input fields for name and email. I am using a for loop to display fields for each used based on number of people.

```
 <input
        type="email"
        name={`email`}
        required
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter"
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e, i);
        }}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        name={`firstname`}
        required
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter"
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e, i);
        }}
      />
```

I have a state:

```
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([{ email: "", firstname: "" }]);
```

I am trying to update the state dynamically for each user. I am doing something like this:

```
const onChange = (e, index) => {

const updatedArray = [...fields];
updatedArray.push(([e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value));

setFields(updatedArray);

};
```

Code isn't working. I am not getting a separate object for each user in state array. I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; your original state is an array of objects. You're not pushing an object; I don't even think that would compile.

Answer (score 0):

the onChange handler should be something like this:

```
const onChange = (e, index) => {
    const inputName = e.currentTarget.name;
    const inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    setFields(prevFields =>
      prevFields.map((pF, i) =>
        i === index ? { ...pF, [inputName]: inputValue } : pF
      )
    );
  };
```

functional update is recommended as the new state depends on the old state and the problem with your snippet is you're not using the `index` to figure out which object to update and the syntax for updating the property in that object is also incorrect.

the two inputs also need a `value` prop:

```
<input
    type="email"
    name={`email`}
    required
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter"
    value={field.email}
    onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e, i);
    }}
/>

<input
    type="text"
    name={`firstname`}
    required
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter"
    value={field.firstname}
    onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e, i);
    }}
/>
```

**Update:**
You need additional code for adding more users, if you want to add a user when a button is clicked:

```
const addUser = () => {
    setFields(prevFields => [
      ...prevFields,
      {
        email: "",
        firstname: ""
      }
    ]);
  };

<button onClick={addUser}>Add User</button>
```

Here's a [React StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ctxkdv) implementing the above solutions

Comment: It only adds info for 1st user and I can even change the info. Does not add info of other users.

Comment: @MusadiqKhan That's because you don't have any logic for adding more users.

Comment: @MusadiqKhan I updated the answer to include a solution for adding more users and added a StackBlitz link.